# How to fold an n-ary Tree in C#

Tags: c#, f#, tree, fold, catamorphism

I would like to do a fold over n-ary Tree data structures. (fold is aka Aggregate in Linq)
I managed to come up with a working solution:

```cs
public static R Aggregate<T, R>(T node,
          Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren,
       Func<T, IEnumerable<R>, R> aggregator)
{
    var childResults = getChildren(node)
                      .Select(c => Aggregate(c, getChildren, aggregator));

    return aggregator(node, childResults);
}
```

`getChildren` is a func defining how to get the children of a given node. It must return an empty IEnumerable for leaf nodes.
The `aggregator` defines how to process a node using the current node and the results of it's children.

The solution seems to work but has some problems:

- The algorithm being recursive, it will blow the stack for deep trees.
  How can I rewrite the function to prevent a stack overflow?
- The algorithm is lazy, but only sort of.
  e.g. if the `aggregator` only uses the `Enumerable.First` result of the child nodes, only the leftmost branch of the tree is traversed. However with `Enumerable.Last` the whole tree is traversed, even though only the rightmost branch is needed for the computation.
  How can I make the algorithm truly lazy?

F# solutions welcome, but C# preferred.

Comment: When you originally built the tree, didn't you have a deep stack?  So why will this algorithm blow the stack when you already had the stack n-deep when building the tree?

Comment: @philologon: the entire tree needn't be in memory at once. An example would be a network crawler.

Comment: Use continuations or a trampoline.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: How?

Comment: @3dGrabber see Brian McNamara's articles in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism#External_links

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: I know those articles. Unfortunately they are about binary trees (not n-ary) in F# and use tail recursion, which does not work in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the tree using an explicit stack, rather than recursion, to avoid consuming stack space:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
    , Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>(source);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

If you want to then traverse "backwards" you can simply adjust the child selector when calling it, rather than calling `Last` instead of `First`:

```
Traverse(root, node => nodes.Reverse());
```

Comment: The question is about folding (aka aggregate, reduce) not traversal.

Comment: @3dGrabber Once you have a flattened sequence of the items you can just use the LINQ `Aggregate` on that sequence.

Comment: Nope. That would transform the tree into a list, and fold the list. The result is (in general) not the same. See requirement: The aggregator defines how to process a node **using the current node and the results of it's children.**

Answer (score 0):

- You have spend memory when traversing trees, if you want to save the stack, instead of depth first switch to breadth first, or some tree traversal technique appropriate to your exact requirement.
- As for making it "properly" lazy, unhook your aggregator from the traversal. Just build out a lazy traversal first (in whatever order you desire) and pass it to your aggregator.

Also, not very sure about your interface choices in relation to your worries about laziness. Enumerable.First vs Enumerable.Last would yield different results for the same tree depending on a change in the provider (getChildren), so why thinking of laziness? So i think the ordering / traversal scheme (even the depth first vs breadth first) should be inherent to your aggregator, or fixed for type of tree? not an external param?